# verilog file with own library import into cadence

Tags: verilog, cadence

I need to import a verilog netlist into cadence. I'm writing the verilog file with my own developed application. I defined several library elements inside the netlist file which are not part of the reference library to check against during the cadence import process.

I need to tell cadence during the import the names and pins (Input & output) of  my new library elements. Can I do this inside one verilog file and how does this basic layout of a verilog file like is look like ?
My Idea not working goes like this ....

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ns 
`resetall
`celldefine
`delay_mode_pa
// Description  : 2 input SMD
module SMD_X (SMD_1,SMD_2);
input  SMD_1;
output SMD_2;
endmodule

// Description  : 4 PIN CLK DEVICE
module CLOCK (CLOCK_1,CLOCK_2,CLOCK_3,CLOCK_4);
input  CLOCK_1,CLOCK_2;
output CLOCK_3,CLOCK_4;
endmodule
//
//  now the net list based on above defined libelements 
//
module  mytest (D+,D-,VCC,VSS) ; 

input D+,D-,VCC,VSS; 

... 
SMD_X X_1 (.SMD_1( net1), .SMD_2( net18));
.. 
..
SMD_X X_2 (.SMD_1( net1), .SMD_2( net27));
...
CLOCK X_10     (.CLOCK_1( net1), .CLOCK_2( net4), .CLOCK_3( net3), .CLOCK_4( net1));
...
endmodule
```

Can I get help on the correct format / verilog syntax for this task?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: cadence does not find the library element in the reference library while importing , I understand this msg ; Cadence should use my new defined library elements now ;  the new library elements are part of my  *.v  file